# Python find and relabel 3d objects in array

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 10x10x10 3d array filled with 0s as background and objects inside them marked with 1s like the one given below. This one has two objects, one in (0,0,0)-(2,2,2) and the other one in (3,5,5)- (5,6,8). Let's say that the object in the coordinate (1,1,1) has to be located (which is the first object here), and the 1s of this object have to be relabeled to 5. Have can this be done?

```
    a = [
[[1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]],
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
]
```

Comment: What is the context? This sounds like homework to me.

Comment: Hi iHowell. It is about finding cells and relabeling them in a 700x1100 image. I'm trying to learn the this so that I can implement it there.

Comment: If there are multiple objects, what do you do with the other objects? Also, what do you mean locate? Find the dimensions of the object? Find the upper-left hand corner?

Comment: Basically find the last 1 when going into each of the six directions. Then you know the position and size of the cube and can set the numbers.

Comment: iHowell: I will have to relabel them as well, but with other numbers. With locate I mean find every 1 that is part of the object and make them 5.

Micheal: The object wouldn't be a cube or rectangle in the majority of times.